# Casting List<T> to my own object

Tags: java, casting

I've got a method called `getBillingCodes` that returns a `List` of objects called `BillingCodes`.

```
@Service
public class BillingCodeService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BillingCodeService.class);

    String sql;

    @Autowired
    private BillingCodeRowMapper billingCodeRowMapper;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<BillingCode> getBillingCodes(int billingCodeId, int limit) {

        sql = [SQL_STATEMENT]";

    List<BillingCode> billingCodeList;

    billingCodeList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{billingCodeId, limit}, billingCodeRowMapper);

        return billingCodeList;
    }
}
```

I would like to change the `getBillingCodes` method so that it still returns a `List` of objects but I like to specify the `List` of objects in a `class` like this

```
@Component
public class BillingCodeList {

    private List<BillingCode> billingCodeList;

    Getter and Setters removed,,.       
}
```

And then change the change the `getBillingCodes` method to:

```
@Service
public class BillingCodeService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BillingCodeService.class);

    String sql;

    @Autowired
    private BillingCodeRowMapper billingCodeRowMapper;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private BillingCodeList billingCodeList;

    public BillingCodeList getBillingCodes(int billingCodeId, int limit) {

        sql = "[SQL_STATEMENT]";

        billingCodeList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{billingCodeId, limit}, billingCodeRowMapper);

        return billingCodeList;
    }
}
```

Setting `billingCodeList = jdbcTemplate.query,,.` gives me an error `no instance(s) of variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to BillingCodeList`. Therefore I've tried to cast the `List<T>` to `BillingCodeList` like this:

```
billingCodeList = (BillingCodeList)jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{billingCodeId, limit}, billingCodeRowMapper);
```

But that gives me a casting error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.test.model.BillingCodeList`. How can I cast `java.util.ArrayList` to `com.test.model.BillingCodeList`

Comment: Your `BillingCodeList` is not of type `ArrayList` given the fact that it's not extending from `ArrayList`, so obviously you get a `ClassCastException`

Comment: @MehdiB. I get the same error even when I extend like `public class BillingCodeList extends ArrayList<BillingCode>` or public class `BillingCodeList extends ArrayList`

Comment: You cannot downcast (narrowing conversion cast) without a cast operator, and it's the wrong way to go anyway. Your type `BillingCodeList ` (terrible name) is nothing but a lot of code to hold a `List`. Just use the `List`. Otherwise set up a constructor for `BillingCodes` (or whatever better name you contrive) that takes a `List<BillingCode>` as an argument and copies it into its internal list, redundantly. Seriously, why do you think you need a wrapper type for a list?

Comment: @LewBloch: *"Your type BillingCodeList (terrible name) is nothing but a lot of code to hold a List"*.  This is not necessarily a bad idea at all.  If a BillingCodeList is a List with added, specific functionality, it is usually better to create a custom type (as the OP has) and compose a List into it (similar to the InsrumentedSet in Effective Java, 2nd Ed. by J. Bloch) rather than use inheritance across package boundaries (ArrayList was not specifically designed for inheritance).  The OP will want to forward those methods that he'll be supporting to the contained List.

Comment: @g3blv: *" I get the same error even when I extend like public class BillingCodeList extends ArrayList<BillingCode>"* ... you probably don't want to get in the habit of doing this anyway.  ArrayList was not specifically designed for inheritance.  *Favor composition over inheritance*.

Comment: @scottb I certainly never recommended inheritance. And the code for `BillingCodeList` here showed no "added, specific functionality", just plain old vanilla `List` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can not cast List to a class object.One thing you can do you can pass BillingCodeList object to BillingCodeRowMapper through constructor and populate the BillingCodeList after creating the BillingCode.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do what you're asking (in effect, you're have an XY problem moment).

To explain, I see that `BillingCodeList` is annotated with `@Component`, which I'm guessing means that it's a Spring component - and you need to do some very fancy footwork to make this work (and it would be inefficient as hell).

I'm guessing that you don't want to re-read all the billing codes each time, and instead you want to cache them in memory. In this case, something like this will work better:

```
@Component
public class BillingCodeListCache {
    @Autowired
    private BillingCodeService billingCodeService;

    private List<BillingCode> billingCodeList;

    public List<BillingCode> getBillingCodes() {
       if(billingCodeList == null) {
           billingCodeList = billingCodeService.getBillingCodes();
       }
       return billingCodeList; // -- or a sublist.
    }
}
```

This way you can also control cache eviction.

Comment: Just as a matter of practice, it's best not to embed implementation (`List`) in a variable name (`billingCodeList`). Collections conventionally use a plural name that reflects purpose, not implementation (`billingCodes`).

Comment: Yes it is Spring. Wouldn't that be the same as `List<BillingCode> billingCodeList;

    billingCodeList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{billingCodeId, limit}, billingCodeRowMapper);`? The reason why I want to create the object is that I want to have a method to print the `List` to a `String` to capture it in a log. I want to create a method with a `foreach` loop rather than having a `foreach` loop for each List that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you are doing this is to have a method to print out the values of the list, then just extend ArrayList or implement the List interface in your class.  Then you can override the toString method to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the solution suggested by Lew Bloch. Passing the `List` as an argument in the `BillingCodes` constructor.

```
@Autowired
    private BillingCodes billingCodesToString(List<BillingCode> billingCodes) {
        return new BillingCodes(billingCodes);
    }
```

And then overriding the `toString()` method in the `BillingCodes` class giving me the ability to to get the `String` like so:

```
billingCodesToString(billingCodes).toString()
```